# Async Await Method will block UI at await point

Tags: c#, linq, async-await

Here is my button event:

```
private async void btnTarget_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (DataBaseDataContext db = new DataBaseDataContext())
    {
        targtGirdView.DataSource = await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            return heavyLinqToSQLQuery;
        });
    }
}
```

for my GridView datasource, I have a heavy database transaction which I put it in an await section. But at this point, the UI will block and I do not know the reason. Where is the problem?

Comment: If you have a database query, then why are you starting a new thread (i.e. `Task.Run`)? Use the asynchronous methods of your database provider...unless this is Oracle, then fuhgeddaboutit.

Comment: Hope, it will help: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html   Possibly, your problem will be soilved by .ConfigureAwait(false); after Task.Run

Comment: sorry mate, cannot reproduce this. may be it freezes because you try to fill too many items into the `targtGirdView` and the drawing of the control takes so much time. Have you tried it without the assignment of the `targtGirdView.DataSource = ` ?

Comment: @Dmitriy, I've just overlooked the fact that `await` captures context - so yes continuation will be resumed on calling thread by default. But in case of  `ConfigureAwait(false)` the setting of `DataSource` should be scheduled on UI thread anyway, so it will end up with the same.

Comment: I tend to agree with @MongZhu, that it seems to be related to the rendering rather than data querying.

Comment: Hm... So strange. So, ReactiveExtensions and LINQ.Async could help him. Maybe.

Comment: Dmytro, it's easy to check by dividing = on 2 parts. I thought an author had already tried to do this and localized a problem by this division...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just solved my problem by adding `.ToList();` at the end of my LINQ query:

```
private async void btnTarget_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (DataBaseDataContext db = new DataBaseDataContext())
    {
        targtGirdView.DataSource = await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            return heavyLinqToSQLQuery.ToList();
        });
    }
}
```

But I have no idea why it is running correctly without blocking UI now. Is there related to lazy loading or what?

Comment: Yes, this is the right solution. You don't even need the Task.Run(). Try `.DataSource = await qyery.ToListAsync()`

Comment: Enumerating the query is what takes time. In your first solution that was done inside the GridView, after assigning the DataSource.

Comment: We probably would have figured that out if you would have provided the query method in the first place

Comment: Your ToList call actually executed the query. This is called delayed execution. And this was done on the ui thread wehn the assignment of the data source takes place

Comment: When the query takes very long (>= 1sec) then the Task.Run might be worth it. But do put the `using(db) {}` inside then, a DbContext isn't thread-safe.

Answer (score 3):

You LINQ query should be async. And code should look something like

```
private async void btnTarget_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (DataBaseDataContext db = new DataBaseDataContext())
    {
        targtGirdView.DataSource = await heavyLinqToSQLQuery.ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: While it is the best way to use `await` in this case, it would be great to see the explanation of why the UI thread is being blocked at `await` point :)

Comment: @the_joric I cannot make LINQ query async, it contains several joins and in `select new` I'm fetching some images from the database then resizing them before assigning.

Comment: Try to start your task with TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning

Comment: This still eaves the (first) enumeration to the DataGrid internals. I don't think this solves the primary problem here. It is a 'better practice' though.